# wp7 Displaying and Linking the Correct Item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, linker

I am trying to figure out how to display only specific content on a new page and I am wondering how to retrieve that data. For instance I have buttons that are generated from parsed data from an xml sheet and when I click on the button I want the button to direct to a new xaml page I have created and have the data associated with that button displayed on the new xaml page.

First I will link some of the code I am using to store my data from my xml page.

```
   `public int countElements = 0;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }


    public void LoadData()
    {

        var elements = from p in unmXdoc.Descendants(dataNamspace +      "vevent").Elements(dataNamspace + "properties")
                       select new ItemViewModel
                       {
                           summary = this.GetElementValue(p, "summary"),
                           description = this.GetElementValue(p, "description"),
                           categories = this.GetElementValue(p, "dtstamp"),
                       };

        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel()
            {
                LineOne = element.summary,
                LineTwo = element.categories,
                LineThree = element.description
            });
            countElements++;
        }

        this.IsDataLoaded = true;`
```

So LineOne is the name of my button and when I click on the button I want LineTwo and LineThree to be loaded on my xaml page that I named LineThreePage.xaml. I will link the xaml code where the buttons are being generated now.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" >
    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <controls:Pivot Title="" Margin="0,64,0,-63">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem>
            <!-- Header="Events"-->
            <controls:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Events" FontSize="48" ></TextBlock>
            </controls:PivotItem.Header>
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <ListBox x:Name="FirstListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                            <Button Margin="8,0,10,0" 
                                    Padding="0,0" 
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                    BorderThickness="0.8"
                                    BorderBrush="Gray"
                                    Background="White"
                                    Width="420" 
                                    Click="Button_Click">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" 
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           Foreground="#8f1020"
                                           Style="{StaticResource   PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                            </Button>
TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-10,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </controls:PivotItem>'
```

So basically when I click button1 I want to navigate to my lineThreePage.xaml and see the LineTwo and LineThree associated with the LineOne on that page.

Finally I have my button click code below!

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/lineThreePage.xaml",   UriKind.Relative));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, what you are looking for is a way to preserve "state" within an application. There are several ways to do this, a couple of them being App.Current.ApplicationLifetimeObjects and Isolated storage.

One of the first things I do when I setup a new WP project is to sort out a service that I would used to preserve state within the app. Assuming that your FirstListBox in the code above binds to an entity of type "ItemViewModel".

1) Setup a generic Isolated storage class service.... bear in mind that you can adapt this to whatever suites your requirement, I've made a few assumptions such as returning nulls when a value is not found in this code,

```
public class IsolateStorageStore
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The iosolated settings store.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IsolatedStorageSettings isolatedStorageSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

    public T ReadValue<T>(string key)
    {
        return isolatedStorageSettings.Contains(key) ? (T)isolatedStorageSettings[key] : default(T);
    }

    public void WriteValue<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        if (isolatedStorageSettings.Contains(key))
        {
            isolatedStorageSettings[key] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            isolatedStorageSettings.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

2) Setup a mechanism for reading/writing a stored value

```
public static class IsolatedStorageManager
{
    private static IsolateStorageStore IsolateStorageStore = new IsolateStorageStore();

    public static ItemViewModel FeedItemViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return IsolateStorageStore.ReadValue<ItemViewModel>("ItemFeedsKey");
        }
        set
        {
            IsolateStorageStore.WriteValue("ItemFeedsKey", value);
        }
    }

    public static object AnotherItem
    {
        get
        {
            return IsolateStorageStore.ReadValue<object>("AnotherItemKey");
        }
        set
        {
            IsolateStorageStore.WriteValue("AnotherItemKey", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you have effectively a service for reading/writing objects to storage, tweak your code to use it.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (sender as Button);

        if (button != null)
        {
            var data = button.DataContext as ItemViewModel;

            if (data != null)
            {
                //Save to isolated storage
                IsolatedStorageManager.FeedItemViewModel = data;

                //redirect to next Page.
                this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/lineThreePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occured, either the sender is not a button or the data context is not of type ItemViewModel");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occured, either the sender is not a button or the data context is not of type ItemViewModel");
        }
    }
```

And finally on your lineThreePage.xaml page, you need to read the values that you have stored in the isolated storage

```
 public lineThreePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindData();
    }


    private void BindData()
    {
        var data = IsolatedStorageManager.FeedItemViewModel;

        if (data != null)
        {
            //Bind the data to a text box in your xaml named "txtDescription"
            txtDescription.Text = data.LineTwo;
        }
    }
```

Do a search for Isolated storage on here to find several resources of how to use it.